# Laravel missing required parameters for route

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm building a blog app in 7.7. I've got most of it working and the application has worked fine up until I've hit one bump. I've defined a "show" function in the controller, added the route, created the blade.php file and added the view yet it's giving me the an error.

Code:

**web.php**

```
Route::name('blog_path')->get('/blogs/{id}', 'Blogs@show');
```

**Blogs.php**

```
public function show($id){

        $blog = Blog::find($id);

        return view('blogs.show', ['blog' => $blog]);
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<h5 class="card-title"><a href="{{ route('blog_path', ['blog' => $blog->id]) }}">{{ $blog->title }}</a></h5>
```

**Error:**

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: blog_path] [URI: blogs/{id}]. (View: D:\xxamp\htdocs\laravel\blog\resources\views\blogs\index.blade.php)
```

Thanks.

Comment: try `['id' => $ blog->id]` instead of `['blog' => $blog->id]`

Comment: that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to replace ['blog' => $blog->id] with ['id' => $ blog->id]

Thanks Aslam.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<h5 class="card-title"><a href="{{ route('blog_path', ['blog' => $blog->id]) }}">{{ $blog->title }}</a></h5>
```

by

```
<h5 class="card-title"><a href="{{ route('blog_path', ['id' => $blog->id]) }}">{{ $blog->title }}</a></h5>
```